# Need help in Developing Blackberry Appln in Mac OS X

Tags: blackberry

I'm an iPhone / iPad developer. 
Wanting to explore in the Blackberry development.

Can someone please guide me through the initial phase.
I use a Mac. Will that be an issue for Blackberry development. Never used Eclipse. Thus such a doubt.

Cheers,
Roshit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for the enviroment:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/macosx.jsp

You can add an emulator using wine Here's an example:

http://azizuysal.com/2009/07/06/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x/

Finally, regarding programing. Well you need to know java and read some documentation like this

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/index.jsp?name=UI+and+Navigation+-+Development+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Java+SDK7.0+Beta&language=English&userType=21&category=Java+Development+Guides+and+API+Reference&subCategory=

Comment: wow.... thanx for the quick response. Will read through all the links you sent.. Thank you once again

Comment: you are welcome. One more thing. Your question has low score. (-2 right now) because it is not really a good one. Please read this so next time you can do better. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions And remember to mark the answer as solution when needed.

Comment: sure thing. Will make sure off this in the future.

Comment: You can also edit your current question so people that downvoted it can upvote it back.